# how to maven release from local without any version control

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin

Just to test maven release works on target repository I am trying to run release-perform from local code base. Currently I am not using any version control.
My pom.xml has entries for maven-release-plugin, created release.properties, and the scm entries for developer connection is like file:///D:/codelocation/ which as per google must be like =scm:svn:file:
My question is since I don't have svn installed, how can I verify maven release for this situation.

Comment: You simly can't use the release plugin without any version control. And why don't you use a version control?

Comment: I do use version control but as of now didn't have may access yet as new joiner in firm. Meanwhile I wanted to test poc mvn release from local dummy code. Its surprising why maven release depends on version control forcefully.

Comment: If you can't use SCM, why don't you just call 'mvn package' and then copy around the jar?